# How to convert java.sql.Date to java.util.Date in dd/MM/yyyy format?

Tags: java, date, java.util.date

I am storing a date to database by converting util date to sql date by using following code

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
sdf.setLenient(false);
java.sql.Date dobSQLDate = null;
Date date = null;
if(!("").equals(userDob)){date = sdf.parse(userDob);dobSQLDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());}
```

now I want to show this date on my page in the dd/mm/yyyy format in which it was taken...
How do I convert this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `format` method on your SimpleDateFormat object.  It takes a java.util.Date object and returns a String formatted based on the format string specified.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ***DateFormatUtils***

```
//Formats you dateto a specific pattern
 DateFormatUtils.format(yourDate, "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Dates do not have a "format" that you can set - they are just an instant in time.

If you want to display a date in a certain format, you must render the date to a String using code such as:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
String dateString = sdf.format(date);
```