# java.sql.Date formatting

Tags: java, date, formatting

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
    System.out.println("utilDate:" + utilDate);
    System.out.println("sqlDate:" + sqlDate);
 }
```

I use this code part and output like this:

```
2013/06/14 12:06:11
2013-06-14
```

I want the output which has date and time data. The parameter of method needs java.sql.Date format. that's why I must convert or change format of `sqlDate`. How can I solve it?

**NOTE**

```
PreparedStatement insertStmt=null;
insertStmt.setDate(parIndex, java.sql.Date);
```

That's why I want java.sql.Date format

Comment: Try `DateFormat.getDateTimeFormat().format(sqlDate)` and see what you get

Comment: That shouldn't be the output of your code. java.util.Date.toString() formats the date in a different way.

Comment: You already have a `Date` which can be formatted using `SimpleDateFormat`, you build your SQL date out of it; by curiosity, why do you want your SQL date formatted too? No trust in `new java.sql.Date()`?

Comment: The `java.sql.Date(long)` constructor sets the time-of-day components to zero GMT. Formatting it as a `java.util.Date` will be fairly misleading.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date(long).

Comment: You need to understand the basics of these two data types. See: [java.util.Date vs java.sql.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2305973/642706).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert java.sql.Date to java.util.Date in dd/MM/yyyy format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344373/how-to-convert-java-sql-date-to-java-util-date-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`java.sql.Date` extends `java.util.Date` so it has the same information but displays it differently because of overridden `toString()` method.

If you do something like this you will see it is the same

```
System.out.println(new java.util.Date(sqlDate.getTime()));
```

It is advised to use `DateFormat` or `SimpleDateFormat` to display data, see the comments.

Comment: +1, nice answer! Which means you can use `SimpleDateFormat` ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use time stamp

```
    Date updated_date=new Date();
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(updated_date.getTime());
    updated_date = timestamp;
```

and make sure  Data type in Database should be `Timestamp` or `Datetime`

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

/**
 * java.util.date to java.sql.date
 */
public class DatesConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Date uDate = new java.util.Date();
        System.out.println("Time in java.util.Date is : " + uDate);
        java.sql.Date sDate = convertUtilToSql(uDate);
        System.out.println("Time in java.sql.Date is : " + sDate);
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY - hh:mm:ss");
        System.out.println("Using a dateFormat date is : " + df.format(uDate));
    }

    private static java.sql.Date convertUtilToSql(java.util.Date uDate) {
        java.sql.Date sDate = new java.sql.Date(uDate.getTime());
        return sDate;
    }
}
```

Use this